# sort Meteor collection according to a variable?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This works:

```
 return articles.find({}, {sort: {'published': -1}, limit: 1});
```

This doesn't:

```
sort_order = 'published';
return articles.find({}, {sort: {sort_order: -1}, limit: 1});
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSON can't use the first value in the key value pair as a variable when it is defined using the `{}` form of definition. You can however, use this way instead:

```
var sort_order = {};

sort_order["published"] = -1;

return articles.find({}, {sort: sort_order, limit: 1});
```

This should get you a final query of:

```
return articles.find({}, {sort: {published:-1}, limit: 1});
```